# storing variable within blade to avoid duplicating same query in another controller

Tags: php, laravel

1. I'm passing the following variable when opening the page :

```
@if(isset($f_posts))
   @foreach($f_posts as $post)
      <a href="/StuffSpot/posts/{{ $post->id }}"> 
         <h4> {{$post->title}}  </h4>
      </a>
   @endforeach
@endif
```

2. In the same page, I pass the following variable, which is passed after loading the page and manually doing a search via a form.

```
@if(isset($post_srch))
   @foreach($post_srch as $post_s)
      <a href=""> 
         <h4> {{$post_s->title}}  </h4>
      </a>
      <br>
   @endforeach
@endif
```

The problem is when submitting the form, the variable passed in point 1 is not loaded because it is not passed in the second controller used in the search form. I can solve this by adding the same query in the search controller and pass the variable again , but I feel there is a more efficient way. 
My question is, after loading the page and passing the variable in point 1,  can I save this variable within the blade so that I can call it without the need to go back to the controller and add a query one more time in the second controller used to pass the variable in point 2 ?

Comment: Can you store the variable in point 1 to the session or in the laravel cache instead of passing it to view? Using this approach variable from the query in point 1 will be stored inside the session (or cache).

Comment: Might [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers) be helpful here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way would be to use "View composers" which allows you to share variables globally. In this case, you need to use a "boot" method from a Service provider. So, try something like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer(['view1', 'view2', 'view3'], function($view) {
        $view->with('var_name', Model::all());
    });
}
```

For example, assuming you need to show all recent posts in three different views:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer(['partials.header', 'partials.footer', 'partial.summary'], 
        function($view) {
        $view->with('posts', Post::recent());
    });
}
```

Or maybe your views are in the same folder:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('partials.*', function($view) {
        $view->with('posts', Post::recent());
    });
}
```

that way, you never have to pass this query inside a Controller.